# Is there a way to use Struts 2.0 and JSF togather in a web application?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, struts2, struts

I've been using Struts 1.x for more than 1 year now, and I've been learning about JSF recently. I know both JSF and Struts are different frameworks but I wanted to use Struts as Action framework and JSF as Component framework in my web application. I'm not sure if we can do that, and couldn't find any materials online regarding this.

Suggestions and links are welcome, Thanks in advance

Comment: I sure wouldn't. Also, using Struts 1 in today's world seems anachronistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts and JSF can be used in a web application, some(or no) changes might be required in the back end but as both the frameworks follow MVC, the "VIEW" tier would be much similar.
As JSF and Struts both have their own advantages, we can use the advantagesof of each combinedly, like ValidationFramework in Struts and JSF components (html components in Struts)

All this I would just only if you have an existing Struts application, can find more detailed information [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=29068)

though the link talks about older versions, i hope it gives basic information

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 

I'm trying to use Struts as the ActionServlet for navigation between pages and JSF for its View. I'm trying to completely avoid JSP and use only XHTML. Now if i did this I'm having trouble populating results from Struts on my XHTML page, since there are no scriplets

Is there any solution for this

Comment: When using JSF for View, use it completely for the VIEW layer (MVC), i would suggest you to use STRUTS for the service layer and JSF for VIEW(which includes navigations as well).